# My element doesn't want to go up on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax.js

Hello I am working on my first parallax scroll project, so I have problem, when I scroll up and down everything is OK, but on the end of the page i want to fix my **boy** to stop little bit before contact, and I did it, but when I fix it he does not want to go up when I scroll. 
Here is my website, http://dev.epartner.rs/  
And where I have problem is:
JS :

```
var kontaktOffset = $('.kontakt').offset().top + 320;

//alert(kontaktOffset);
if (wScroll > kontaktOffset - ($(window).height() / 0.9)) {

    var eboy = $('#eboy');
    top=$('#eboy').css('top');
    right= $('#eboy').css('right');
    left=$('#eboy').css('left');
    bottom=$('#eboy').css('bottom');
$('#eboy').css({'position':'absolute','top':top,'right':right,'left':left,'bottom':bottom});


}else {
    $('#eboy').removeProp({'bottom':bottom});
    // $('#eboy').removeAttr({'bottom':bottom});
```

I think to I need to remove bottom from my **eboy** but I am not sure is it good solution or I need to do something else.
If anyone knows how to fix it bee free to give any solution or advice.

Answer (score 0):

In the else part change it to:

```
$('#eboy').css({'bottom':'auto', 'top': 'auto'});
```

Since you seem to be moving it using margin, and bottom auto computes. But when you set bottom to a value, it overrides your dynamic margin.

Comment: I have added the css required, that should help.